# How can I embed login credentials in a iframe src?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, autologin

How can i pass user auto login in  src url?

```
   <iframe src="https://secure.aws.XXX.com/app/share/28228b0ccf0a987" width="1060px" height="1100px"></iframe>
```

I tried this but display the login screen

```
   <iframe src="https://secure.aws.XXX.com/app/share/28228b0ccf0a987?username=username&password=password" width="1060px" height="1100px"></iframe>
```

Comment: That will depend, is it using HTTP Basic Authentication or a form in which you have to submit your credentials?

Comment: @Havenard Thanks! what do you mean by HTTP Basic Authentication or a form?

Comment: note:  even though it is in an iFrame, including password (and for that matter username)  in the url is very unsecure. It's pretty easy to load the content from an iFrame outside the frame

Comment: @nomistic Thanks! there is another login to access and see the content in the `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have the page login to something at the same time they are viewing it, you might not be able to do this as your request may need to be a `POST` method, in which case, your `iframe` will only perform a `GET` request.   You may need to use something like AJAX to do what you need.

Also, as per Havenard's comment, it depends on the authentication method that may be needed by the authenticating server.  This would require a better understanding of the service you are connecting to as it may not allow for authentication the way you are trying to use.